# Adding onclick events to dynamically generated images in android relative layout

Tags: android, onclick, mouseevent, onclicklistener

I'm doing a project in which images are added dynamically to the screen. There are absolutely no XML references created at compile-time because the entire thing is generated dynamically.

[image: How my app looks at runtime]

The entire thing is generated dynamically. Now, I want to know how to add an onclick event to each of the images. Basically, when an image is clicked, another image with a darker shade should appear (it is basically an answer sheet so it is like a bubble is shaded). I would like some sample code in this context. I'm new to Android and am pretty much lost now.

Please help!

P.S. If the source code is required, I'll gladly put it up. Please let me know.

EDIT: Putting up the code:

```
package ekalavya.pratnala.quiz;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Beginning of variable declarations
    File quizSpecs = new File("mnt/sdcard/teacher_1.csv"); // Read the file
    BufferedReader csvReader = null;
    String line = ""; // Storing each line in a string
    StringTokenizer currentLine = null;
    int noOfQuestions = 0; // Number of questions in the quiz
    int time = 0; // Duration of the quiz
    int[][] quizData; // Storing the quiz specifications in an integer array
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; // Loop variables
    int[][] questionImages = {
            { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                    R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
                    R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j },
            { R.drawable.a_checked, R.drawable.b_checked,
                    R.drawable.c_checked, R.drawable.d_checked,
                    R.drawable.e_checked, R.drawable.f_checked,
                    R.drawable.g_checked, R.drawable.h_checked,
                    R.drawable.i_checked, R.drawable.j_checked },
            { R.drawable.zero, R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
                    R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
                    R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
                    R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.decimal },
            { R.drawable.zero_checked, R.drawable.one_checked,
                    R.drawable.two_checked, R.drawable.three_checked,
                    R.drawable.four_checked, R.drawable.five_checked,
                    R.drawable.six_checked, R.drawable.seven_checked,
                    R.drawable.eight_checked, R.drawable.nine_checked,
                    R.drawable.decimal_checked } };
    int previd = 0;
    // End of variable declarations

    try {
        csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(quizSpecs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        line = csvReader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    noOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    time = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    // System.out.println(noOfQuestions + " " + time);
    while (currentLine.hasMoreTokens()) {
        currentLine.nextToken();
    }
    quizData = new int[noOfQuestions][6];
    for (i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        try {
            line = csvReader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            quizData[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
            // System.out.println(quizData[i][j]);
        }
    }
    try {
        csvReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ScrollView s1 = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout r1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    for (i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        System.out.println(quizData[i][2]);
        TextView questionNo = new TextView(this);
        questionNo.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        questionNo.setId(1000 * (i + 1));
        questionNo.setTextSize(18);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previd);
        previd = (1000 * (i + 1));
        questionNo.setLayoutParams(p1);
        r1.addView(questionNo, p1);
        switch (quizData[i][1]) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
                option.setImageResource(questionImages[0][j]);
                option.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + j + 1);
                if (j >= quizData[i][2]) {
                    option.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    option.setEnabled(false);
                }
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ((1000 * i) + 1));
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        ((1000 * (i + 1)) + j));
                previd = ((1000 * (i + 1)) + j);
                option.setLayoutParams(params);
                r1.addView(option, params);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for (j = 0; j < (quizData[i][3] == 0 ? quizData[i][2]
                    + quizData[i][3] : quizData[i][2] + quizData[i][3] + 1); j++) {
                for (k = 10; k > -1; k--) {
                    ImageView num = new ImageView(this);
                    num.setImageResource(questionImages[2][10 - k]);
                    num.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k + 1);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if (j == 0) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)));
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * (j - 1)) + k + 1);
                    }
                    if (k == 10) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (1000 * i) + 1);
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                                ((1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k + 2));
                    }
                    num.setLayoutParams(params);
                    r1.addView(num, params);
                }
            }
            previd = (1000 * (i + 1)) + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            for (j = quizData[i][2] - 1; j > -1; j--) {
                for (k = 0; k < quizData[i][3]; k++) {
                    ImageView match = new ImageView(this);
                    match.setImageResource(questionImages[0][k]);
                    match.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k + 1);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if (k == 0) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)));
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k);
                    }
                    if (j == quizData[i][2] - 1) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (1000 * i) + 1);
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * (j + 1)) + k + 1);
                    }
                    match.setLayoutParams(params);
                    r1.addView(match, params);
                }
            }
            previd = (1000 * (i + 1)) + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    s1.addView(r1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    this.setContentView(s1);
}
}
```

Comment: Post, what have you tried earlier?

Comment: The thing is I don't know what to do. I'm completely clueless. Wherever I see, the onClick event is given to something which has been created in the XML file at compile time. In this, everything is generated dynamically.

Also, do you mean you want to see the code?

Comment: Does each row of hte view correspond to one question?

Comment: @Sana Each question number on the left represents a new question. The second and third are match the following. The fourth is integer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement OnClickListener in your Activity

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {
   .
   .
   .


     for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
                option.setImageResource(questionImages[0][j]);
                option.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + j + 1);
                option.setOnClickListener(this);  // setOnClickListener to your dynamically Image view.. 
                if (j >= quizData[i][2]) {
                    option.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    option.setEnabled(false);
                }
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ((1000 * i) + 1));
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        ((1000 * (i + 1)) + j));
                previd = ((1000 * (i + 1)) + j);
                option.setLayoutParams(params);
                r1.addView(option, params);
            }
```

// Override onClick and put switch case for differentiate imageview's click..

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case //id of your dynamically imageview :

            break;
                }
         }
    }
```

Comment: How do I access the image resource of the clicked Image? I can't find a getImageResource() function

Comment: Sorry, You can't. There is no android method for it.. For this you have to make some trick. like, a hashmap function which will store imageview id as a key and image resource path or name as a value. and onclick get those value using imageview's id as key..

Comment: Could you explain little more?

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to go about?

Comment: HashMap<Integer,Integer> imageResource = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); in for loop.. imageResource.put(option.getId(),questionImages[0][j]); and when you want to get in onClick(0 just int resource = imageResource.get(view.getId());

Comment: What is HashMap<Integer,Integer> imageResource ?

Comment: Its HashMap collection class from JAVA. Like Array List.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? I'm completely new to this.

Comment: hey is give me error when i write switch condition                 im= new ImageView(TestActivity.this);                            public void onClick(View v) {
 
 switch (v.getId()) 
 {
 case R.id.im:
   break;

 default:
  break;
 }
 
}

Comment: @AndroidDepartment - Which type of error? Can you post the error and error code line?

Comment: after add this i add the  public static final int img=50000; and use this switch condition for getting dynamic imageview clicked position but my onclick is not working public void onClick(View v) {
 
 Log.e("Clicked","----->"+v.getId());
 switch (v.getId()) 
 {
 case img:
     Log.e("Clicked","----->"+v.getId());
   break;

 default:
  break;
 }
 
}

Comment: i not getting onclick event now error is not coming but not getting imageview click event on onclick

Comment: @AndroidDepartment - Did you implement onClickLister to ImageView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326705/how-to-get-dynamically-created-imageview-or-textview-clicked-id-or-position-in-a

Answer (score 0):

In Java, just run the setOnClickListener method on your ImageViews like so:

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
        iv.setImageResource(R.id.darkbubble);
        //Do anything else you would like
    }
});
```

Comment: 2 questions. What is mImageView? Or is it just ImageView?
And also, you have given setImageResource. But the code is different for each A you see (i.e. there are 2 possible things which can happen). So I need something which can detect the id of the image clicked.